# Optimization problem with Laplacian constraints

Tags: optimization, constraints, laplacian

I am trying to solve the following optimization problem and trying to obtain a set of values `x_1, x_2, ..., x_k` as follows:

```
argmin Σx_i * a_i
subject to <x_1, x_2, ..., x_k> ~ Lap(m, b)
```

The terms a_i are constants, and the values x_i are drawn from a laplace distribution with mean m and scale parameter b. Hence the resulting outputs are generated from a Laplacian distribution. What is this kind of constraint called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a general form of [Lasso regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)). Adding L1 regularization can often been seen as enforcing a Laplace prior on your data (see the [Bayesian interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)#Bayesian_interpretation)). You could try solving:

```
argmin Σx_i * a_i + 1/b Σ|x_i - m|
```

You could try solving this using (sub)-gradient methods or [proximal minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximal_gradient_methods_for_learning#Lasso_regularization).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into these topics.